# storing and retrieving location using firebase

Tags: android, location, android-location, sharing

i am using firebase database for storing users information after registering them in the android app after Firebase authentication, its a location sharing app where a user can see other user's location on selecting a user from registered users list. The question is that how can I store or get user's location and then retrieve it and show it to the other users.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a CRUD with firebase, than firebase will automaticly